# Outer or inner link url

Tags: python, django

I want to know if a href="url" attribute is an outer or inner URL. How can I do it in django. Please help.
May be like this

```
if URL.find("www.sameurl.com") == -1 and URL.find("sameurl.com")==-1:
   do
else:
   do
```

Comment: What is URL?  a model? a variable? part of an html string?

Comment: Instead of `URL.find("sameurl.com")==-1`, use `"sameurl.com" in URL`. It's much cleaner.

Comment: By outer/inner do you mean absolute/relative? http://kb.iu.edu/data/abwp.html

Comment: @udi I think he means "belonging to the same domain"

Comment: I want change that URLs which are linked to other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MY_DOMAIN = "sameurl.com"

import urlparse
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
if parsed.netloc=='' or parsed.netloc.endswith(MY_DOMAIN):
    # internal
else:
    # external
```